# How to read .env/.env.local file in Next.js (App Router)

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, .env, app-router

I cannot read the API values in .env / .env.local file in next.js with latest App Router.

As far as I understand, the .env should be enabled under the hood in react.

I have tried many methods from here, but still failed.

Including installed `dotenv` and

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const env = dotenv.config().parsed;
```

I tried to log out in

- session file - I need to use it here
- server side file - I could obtain value
- client side file (with `"use client";`)

## Here are the steps I tried

root file

`.env`

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID='values'
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="values"
```

client side file

```
"use client";

useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)   ===> undefined
},[])
```

`lib/session.ts`

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { NextAuthOptions, User } from "next-auth";
import { AdapterUser } from "next-auth/adapters";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import jsonwebtoken from "jsonwebtoken";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { SessionInterface } from "@/common.types";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId:
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID|| "",  ===>  could not obtain value
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET || "",
    }),
  ],
```

=========

So i checked this page from NextJs https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables,

and reset `.env` to `.env.local`

still undefined

=========

I installed `dotenv`

client side file

```
"use client";

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const env = dotenv.config().parsed; 

useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)   ===> undefined
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the env variables using `process.env.<VARIABLE_NAME>` in NextJS.

If that didn't work for you, please share what all you tried and what the result was.

Comment: I just updated my post with more detials

Comment: Are you getting undefined from the server components too? In your question, you mentioned that you were getting undefined from server component too. But, just to clarify, did you try accessing `process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` from the server component?